# ASP.NET MVC How to pass data from a GET ActionResult to the POST ActionResult of the same view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, actionresult

I have these create ActionResults:

```
   // GET: WC_Inbox/Create
        public ActionResult Create(int? id)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Employee ID was: " + id);
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Employee employee = db.Employees.Find(id);
            if (employee == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            string fullName = employee.First_Name + " " + employee.Last_Name;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Employee full name: " + fullName);
            ViewBag.EmployeeID = id;
            ViewBag.Name = fullName;
            ViewBag.Status = "Pending";
            return View();
        }

        // POST: WC_Inbox/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ID,InboxID,EmployeeID,Org_Number,Hire_Date,Job_Title,Work_Schedule,Injury_Date,Injury_Time,DOT_12,Start_Time,Injured_Body_Part,Side,Missing_Work,Return_to_Work_Date,Doctors_Release,Treatment,Injury_Description,Equipment,Witness,Questioned,Medical_History,Inbox_Submitted,Comments,User_Email,Contact_Email,Specialist_Email,Optional_Email,Optional_Email2,Optional_Email3,Optional_Email4,Status,Add_User,Date_Added")] WC_Inbox wC_Inbox)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                //Get logged in windows user, get the date right now, and create the wcInbox unique ID
                var userName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
                wC_Inbox.Add_User = userName;
                wC_Inbox.Date_Added = DateTime.Today;
                db.WC_Inbox.Add(wC_Inbox);
                db.SaveChanges();
                SendEmailIQ();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            ViewBag.EmployeeID = new SelectList(db.Employees, "ID", "First_Name", wC_Inbox.EmployeeID);
            return View(wC_Inbox);
        }
```

I need to pass the value `fullName` from the GET method to the POST method. There are several posts asking how to pass data from one action result to another, but I haven't seen one like this. I don't know how to pass the data from GET Create to POST Create or how to retrieve data once it is sent.

Comment: Can you pls be more certain? I can't see where you are trying to pass the value fullname. Could you post your Get and Post methods and how are you going to pass it.

Comment: Both the get and post methods have been given... they are there in the question lol. And my question is just that, "how to pass it".

Comment: I still can'see what are needed to pass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't send or retrieve data from your get method at the point that you are needing it in the post method due to the fact that the Get method has finished executing and been cleaned up. I would advise you to either add a hidden field on the page to be posted when the post request is made or to re-fetch the data in the post request.

Comment: Ah this makes sense. In that case I'll just do the hidden field. I had thought of doing that, but it seemed like not the right way of going about it. Thank you for the help!